# Can't force the pdf download with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, pdfkit

I'm using express.js with pdfkit, trying to generate a pdf and force a download in a webbrowser.

I defined static location where the pdf is stored, but when I want to read this location and download the file nothing happens. I've tried also setting headers, but that didn't work.

I've read that that may have something to do with the ports on which server and front-end is running. In my case these are: 4200 (Angular) and 8080 (Node.js)

Here is fragment of the server code:

```
var downl = doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('C:/Users/Martyna/Desktop/test pdfow/out.pdf') );

doc.end();

downl.on('finish', function() {
    res.download('C:/Users/Martyna/Desktop/test pdfow/out.pdf', 'out.pdf');
})
```

Comment: How are you making the request from the client? What do you see in the Network section of your browser's dev tools: do you see the request and do you see a response coming back?

Comment: createAuthHeaders() {
    this.loadToken();
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': this.authToken
      })
    });
  }

  loadToken() {
    this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  testGetId(cv: Cv) {
    this.createAuthHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.domain + '/konto-uzytkownika/' + cv.cvId, this.options);
  }

Comment: And in my dev tools I get the proper response type: 
"application/pdf"
even though I'm not setting it in server response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the below headers to your response. To have the file downloaded rather than viewed

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="You_File_Name.pdf"
```

To indicate to the browser that the file should be viewed in the browser:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="You_File_Name.pdf"
```

Comment: I've added: 

         res.writeHead(200, {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                   'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=out.pdf'
               });

And I get an error in my console: 
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way - 

res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.set('Content-Type', 'attachment; filename="You_File_Name.pdf"');
res.sendFile(__dirname, 'files/out.pdf');

Comment: Got it! Setting content-type and content-disposition as you said actually helped, thank you! Also I specifed responseType on client site to Blob and then in http get method I wrote this:

  testGetId(cv: Cv) {
    this.createAuthHeaders2();
    return this.http.get(this.domain + '/konto-uzytkownika/' + cv.cvId, this.options).subscribe(res => {     
      console.log(res) 
      var blob = new Blob([res.blob()], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      saveAs(blob, "cv.pdf");
    });
  }

Comment: Woohoo, that's amazing. Why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry,  I'm newbie in stackoverflow and I forgot! Done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with just reading file and sending it as a response.
this code works for me!

```
fs.readFile('C:/Users/Martyna/Desktop/test pdfow/out.pdf',(err,data)=>{
if(err){
  consol.log(err);
}else {
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=your_file_name_for_client.pdf');

res.send(data)
}
})
```